# Update error, not enough space

Tags: update-manager, 15.10

When i try to update ubuntu i get the next error, how do i solve it? :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have a separate `boot` partition.
The Update is asking for more space in `boot` partition.
Your screenshot is giving the details of `root` partition.
**How to solve?**
Install **GParted** (Available in `Software Centre`).
You will be able to see detailed information about the partition sizes using GParted.
It has a nice Graphical Interface that will let you compress or expand the partitions as per your need.
Note: You need free-space on either side of a partition to expand it.
If you don't have free space, you will have to compress the nearby partition to expand it.
 
Check out detailed tutorial on GParted [here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions).